# getting error while posting data of uid and token ( 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'post' )

Tags: django, post, wsgi, django-class-based-views, uid

I created class based view to access uid and token . Here I create one web page which have one button of activate user. I am sending one uid and token to user email . now I want to post that uid and token when user click on button. I create this code in view for post uid and token. But getting error on posting **(WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'post)**

views.py

```
class ActivationView(View):
def get (self, request, uid, token):
    print('get called in activate_user')
    return render(request, 'activate.html')

def post (self, request, uid, token):
    print('UID : ', uid)
    print('Token : ', token)
    payload = json.dumps({'uid': uid, 'token': token})
    print("payload : " , payload)
    protocol = 'https://' if request.is_secure() else 'http://'
    web_url = protocol + request.get_host() + '/'
    post_url = web_url + ACTIVATION_BASE_ROUTE
    print('post_url : ' + post_url)
    response = request.post(post_url, data = payload)
    return HttpResponse(response.text)
```

activate.html

```
    <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
           <td ><button type="submit">Click Here For Activate Account</button></td>
     </form>
```

How can I post it on same page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) not [request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects)

Give this a try

```
import requests

class ActivationView(View):
    
    def post (self, request, uid, token):
        ...
        response = requests.post(post_url, data = payload)
        return HttpResponse(response.text)
```